# Delphi: SetLength() on argument of type "array of TObject"

Tags: delphi, arrays, object, resize

I'm trying to resize an array of a certain class passed as an argument, e.g.

```
procedure Resize(MyArray: Array of TObject);
begin
  SetLength(MyArray, 100);
end;
```

However, this raises an error "E2008 Incompatible types". Is it true that you can't do this (I've seen rumors, but no official documentation) or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't defined the type explicitly. So the compiler has problems matching them. If you define the type like:

```
type
  TObjectArray = array of TObject;
```

There is no doubt about it and (thanks to Mghie) you should be using a var parameter because resising likely cause a change in the pointer.

```
procedure Resize(var MyArray: TObjectArray);
begin
  SetLength(MyArray, 100);
end;
```

Comment: This answer misses the key point which is the difference between open arrays and dyanmic arrays.

Answer (score 9):

You are mixing *open arrays* (the parameter of Resize) and *dynamic arrays* (what SetLength expects). See [here](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html) for an explanation - especially the part titled "Confusion".