# Get length of custom type of array

Tags: arrays, delphi, types, dynamic-arrays

I want to get the length of a array which is declared as a custom type, and the custom type is declared as an array. I have followed this route to allow me to pass the array as reference.

Here is my code:

```
type
    TDLLPointerReference = Record
        Pointer  : Pointer;
        IconName : Integer;
        DLLType  : TDLLType;
    end;

type
 TReffArray = array of TDLLPointerReference;

//compressor array's
    PARCompressors : TReffArray;
    PAROnCompressors : TReffArray;
    PARBaseCompressors : TReffArray;
    PARReserveCompressors : TReffArray;
    PARUnavailableCompressors : TReffArray;

function TCompressorPrioritiser.GetCompListLength(Aname : string250): integer;
var
i, k : integer;
begin
    i := ConvertStringtoIndex(AName);   //function to translate comp name to index
    case i of
        0 : k := length(PARCompressors);
        1 : k := length(PAROnCompressors);
        2 : k := length(PARBaseCompressors);
        3 : k := length(PARReserveCompressors);
        4 : k := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);
    else k := 0;
    end;
    result := k;//does not executes

    //test code begin Only added afterward
    PARUnavailableCompressors[1].Pointer := 0;  //executes
    k := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);     //executes
    i := k; //does not executes
    result := 5; //executes
    //test code ends
end;
```

This function is responsible for the custom type of array.

```
procedure TCompressorPrioritiser.MoveComp(AIndex : integer; var ACompListOut : TReffArray;var ACompListIn : TReffArray);
var
i : integer;
begin
//This will move a compressor at the index in ACompListOut to  ACompListin
    setlength(ACompListIn, length(ACompListIn)+1);
    ACompListIn[length(ACompListIn)-1] :=  ACompListOut[AIndex];
    For i := Aindex to length(ACompListOut)-2 do
    begin
        ACompListOut[i] := ACompListOut[i+1];
    end;
    setlength(ACompListOut, length(ACompListOut)-1);
end;
```

Is there any way to perhaps get the array length?
Or change the bottom function so I can send the array's through as parameters.

The main problem is that the lines I marked as do not compile, dont seem to run. When I set a breakpoint, those lines of code are just skipped and a breakpoint cannot be set there. Because what I want to do is get the length of the array. The function is suppose to return it, but it skips the return function. Also if a add a watch the the var k, delphi tells me that K is unavailable to to optimization although it was only a line back it was used. The same happens when I add a watch to var i.

I did some further testing. Now the first version of the function every line executes. The second version the line result := k doesn't execute, why is that?

1st version

```
function TCompressorPrioritiser.GetCompListLength(Aname : string250): integer;
var
i, k : integer;
begin
    i := ConvertStringtoIndex(AName);   //function to translate comp name to index
    case i of
        0 : k := length(PARCompressors);
        1 : k := length(PAROnCompressors);
        2 : k := length(PARBaseCompressors);
        3 : k := length(PARReserveCompressors);
        4 : k := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);
    else k := 0;
    end;
    result := k;//executes

    //test code begin
    k := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);     //executes
    //test code ends
end;
```

2 version

```
function TCompressorPrioritiser.GetCompListLength(Aname : string250): integer;
var
i, k : integer;
begin
    i := ConvertStringtoIndex(AName);   //function to translate comp name to index
    case i of
        0 : k := length(PARCompressors);
        1 : k := length(PAROnCompressors);
        2 : k := length(PARBaseCompressors);
        3 : k := length(PARReserveCompressors);
        4 : k := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);
    else k := 0;
    end;
    result := k;//does not executes

    //test code begin
    //k := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);     
    //test code ends
end;
```

Edit
Changed compressor to array. Its a array of references to compressor, didn't type correctly sorry.

Edit2
Added problem statement at the bottom

Edit3
Changed code to reflect code changes recommended. And added secondary part of further testing.

EDIT4

I got the code to work, I get the result I am looking for but I dont get as too why I need the line :"k := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);     //executes" It serves no purpose but without that line, the "result :=k" line does not executes. If I replace the K := length line with just K:=6, the result := k line also doesn't execute.  So why do I need that other line?

```
function TCompressorPrioritiser.GetCompListLength(Aname : string250): integer;
var
i, k : integer;
begin
    k := 0;
    i := ConvertStringtoIndex(AName);   //function to translate comp name to index
    case i of
        0 : k := length(PARCompressors);
        1 : k := length(PAROnCompressors);
        2 : k := length(PARBaseCompressors);
        3 : k := length(PARReserveCompressors);
        4 : k := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);
    else k := 0;
    end;
    result := k;
    k := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);     //Withint this line code above line does not execute
    //k :=6;  // this does not have the same effect as the above line
end;
```

Comment: "does not compile" what do you mean ? what exactly is text of error and in which line/column of the sources ? // "Is there any way to perhaps get the compressor length?" There is no "compressor" in the quoted function // "Or change the bottom function so I can send the array's through as parameters" - sure, change "out" to "var" and you can send that parameter both in and out.

Comment: In your example `ACompListOut` is defined as an `out` parameter of the `MoveComp()` method, but you read data out of it at `ACompListIn[length(ACompListIn)-1] :=  ACompListOut[AIndex];` Though the compiler allows to so, it is **bad programming practice**.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Not least because the code which you claim does not compile, in fact does. An SSCCE is required.

Comment: I could perhaps have been more clear about the not compile part. It compiles and run. But when I add breakpoints, it skips the line that I marked as do not compile.

Comment: Changing the out to var in the procedure and removing the custom type and just making the variables array's still gives me the incompatible types at the line where I set the length of the array ("setlength(ACompListIn, length(ACompListIn)+1);"). I get this error [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642350/delphi-setlength-on-argument-of-type-array-of-tobject)

Comment: Nobody asked you to change the parameter to an open array. Just change `out` to `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Length()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Length) to find the length of an array.

The reason that you cannot set breakpoints on the lines that you mark is that the compiler has optimised them away. The compiler has determined that they have no impact.

For instance, you assign one value to `Result`, and then later assign a different value to `Result` without reading from `Result` in the intervening time. Therefore the first assignment is pointless and can be removed.

And the assignment to `i` is the same. You don't refer to the local variable `i` in any code that executes after the assignment, and since the assignment has no side-effects it can be removed. The compiler does warn you of this. I hope you have enabled warnings and take notice of them.

Disabling optimization in the compiler options will stop the compiler from excising those lines of code.

---

Regarding your second update, again the optimizer is confusing you. The compiler has detected that the variable `k` is superfluous and assigns directly to `Result`. You can write that function like this:

```
function TCompressorPrioritiser.GetCompListLength(Aname : string250): integer;
begin
  case ConvertStringtoIndex(AName) of
  0 : Result := length(PARCompressors);
  1 : Result := length(PAROnCompressors);
  2 : Result := length(PARBaseCompressors);
  3 : Result := length(PARReserveCompressors);
  4 : Result := length(PARUnavailableCompressors);
  else Result := 0;
  end;
end;
```

---

I must also point out that `ACompListOut` is incorrectly declared as an `out` parameter. Since you read it inside the function, it must be declared as `var`.

---

I would also suggest that it might be time to stop using short strings and move on to `string`.

Comment: I have changed that to var, read my comment above, the second result was only added later in.

Comment: You need to change `out` to `var`. It turns out that Delphi's implementation of `out` is rubbish and the compiler writes out the same code. But it is semantically wrong as you have it.

Comment: Edit 4 is very odd. Why are you writing that rather than the code in my answer?

Comment: That was how I had written it the first time, but I could not test the result of directly in the function. K was only meant to be temporary. That last line is the only way I can assign a break point to the line result := k. But you were correct, the result is only removed due to optimization.

Comment: When you are debugging you should disable optimisation. Enable it for release builds, but for dev and debug it just hinders you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of an type array, use the Length method:

```
type
    TTestRecord = record
        Id: Integer;
        Name: String;
    end;

    TTestRecordArray = array of TTestRecord;

...

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    myArray: TTestRecordArray;
    mySize: Integer;
begin
    SetLength( myArray, 100 );
    ShowMessage( IntToStr( Length( myArray ) ) );
end;
```

But that's already what you are doing in your `MoveComp`, so there is something wrong elsewhere. And `i := k;` compiles when i and k are integer, no matter what, so your debugging logic seems wrong to me...

EDIT >> based on your updated question, your problem is that the `Result := k;` line seems to be skipped during execution. I would expect this behavior since you have a `Result := 5;` line after that, so no need for the compiler to bother with your `Result := k;`. Remove the code between `//test code begins` and `//test code ends`, and see what is happening now...

Comment: I'm not pretty sure what the OP wants. He wrote _size_ and not _length_ in the question which **inho** means _size of bytes occupied from memory_ which will be `Length(myArray) * SizeOf(TTestRecord)` (in your case).

Comment: See my edit in my post and my comment on the above comments. Did that make it clearer to what is wrong and what I want?

Comment: Not at all unfortunately. You didn't told us what is wrong with your code...

Comment: Sorry about that, is it better this time?

Comment: I added the result := 5 after I first encountered the problem, just too see if it will actually run code after the first result, because at that time it went straight to the end, which was below the result := k; part. So removal of that makes no differance

Comment: If you remove the Result := 5; statement, what is the value returned by your method ?

Comment: @blackwolfsa You need to make your mind up as to what the question really is. As written you are asking why the marked lines are skipped in the debugger. That question has been answered. In my view this question is over. Please please do not expect us to debug the rest of your code, the code that we cannot see.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question about why the line does not execute is directly related to my problem. I want to get the length of those arrays. The line that is skipped is blocking me from getting that. The solution I want is either to get the line to execute, or another entirely different solution. I only posted the current not working solution here to so what I have don't up until this point in time.

Comment: You are getting very confused. Your code does assign to `Result`. Are you claiming otherwise?

Comment: As @David said, you are confused. Result is assigned. Your method returns "something". Now, maybe this value doesn't seem to be correct to you, but the problem lies elsewhere. Maybe in your <code>ConvertStringtoIndex</code> method ?

Comment: It would really help if you did not keep changing the question over and over and tried really hard to understand what we are telling you. If you don't understand us, say so. But these endless question changes make it very difficult for us to explain because the ground keeps shifting underneath us.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am trying my best to clarify the question. But look at edit4 I manged to get the code working accidentally. My code executes and returns the values I expect. The problem now is that I have another line in my code that is not necessary at all, but without that line, the result line does not execute.

Comment: @David has already answered this : due to compiler optimization. So you should accept his answer.